# 設定ファイルに存在していたら引数に設定し、なければ引数に入れない方法

Tags: python

elseの場合、dictを入れる必要があるところに、NoneTypeを入れているので、Type Errorになっています。

```
def definition(config:dict):
    if A in config:
        A = config['A']
    else:
        A = None
    create_instance(
        OptionA=A
    )
def create_instance(OptionA:dict):
....
```

やりたいこととしてはconfigにAというdictが存在していたらcreate_instanceのOptionAにconfig['A']というdictをいれて、なければ引数に何も入れないのと同じ処理をしたいと思っています。

そもそも入れる方が違う時点で考え方が間違っているのだとは思っていますが、どうやって解決したらよいか悩んでいます。

暫定対応として以下のようにすれば問題ないと思いますが、cretate_instanceの引数が複数になったときに他の引数でも同じようなことをやるとifだらけになってしまいそうで、他に良い方法があれば教えていただけますと幸いです。

```
if A in config:
     A = config['A']
    create_instance(
        OptionA=A
    )
else:
    A = None
    create_instance()
```

Comment: dictは `{key1,: value1, key2: value2, ...}` の構造で, `A = config[key]` とすると `key`に対する `value`が代入されます。`cretate_instance()`の引数が少し不明なので, 構造を明確にしたほうがよいかも。質問通りの構造なら `config` は dictのネストした構造でしょうか？

Comment: 引数が増えた場合のことは取り敢えず脇に置いておいて、最初のコードの`A = None`の部分を空のdict(`A = {}`)にするのは可能(あるいは効果がある)でしょうか？

Comment: @oriri  configはdictのネスト構造です。引数OptionAもdictのネスト構造になってます。

Comment: @kunif  引数OptionAもdictのネスト構造になっており、`A={}`をいれるとOptionAの下階層のkeyが必須となっていてエラーなってしまいます。

Comment: ```OptionA: {A_1: xxx, A_2: yyy}```引数としてOptionAを与えたときにA_1とA_2が必須項目としてチェックされるようになっています。なので、`A = {A_1: None, A_2: None}`もエラーとなってしまいます。

Comment: その辺のことは @oriri さんもコメントしたように、コメント欄ではなく記事の方に追記した方が良いでしょう。そういうことだと`create_instance()`側の処理も含めて変更することを考えた方が良いのでは？

Comment: `def create_instance(OptionA:dict):` で引数なし (`create_instance()`)だとエラーになるのでは？
また, `create_instance(None)`もエラー`create_instance({})`もエラー出るなら
`create_instance`側で対処(回避？)すればよい気がします

Answer (score 0):

すこし質問に挙げられているコードが違う気がしますが、

- configにキーAがあるときにはキーワード付き引数OptionAで関数を呼びたい
- configにキーAがないときにはキーワード引数なしで関数を呼びたい

という質問と解釈しました。

```py
kwargs = {}
if 'A' in config;
    kwargs['OptionA'] = config['A']

create_instance(**kwargs)  #キーワード引数をdictから展開して呼び出し
```

とすれば良いと思います。